# How to align views vertically in the top of a sheet in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to align views in the top of a modal sheet vertically. The parent view has `NavigationView` and `VStack` inside it.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var selection: Int = 0
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("...")) {
                    Text("...").tag(0)
                    Text("...").tag(1)
                }
                .border(Color.gray)
                
                TextField("# edit", text: $text)
                .padding(8.0)
                .border(Color.gray)
                
                Spacer()
                .border(Color.gray)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button {
                
            } label: { Text("Done") })
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoView()
    }
}
```

However extra space appears in the preview.

[image]

How can I remove this space? Is this issue affected by the alignment of `NavigationView` and `VStack`? Or does `Picker` need an extra space on the top? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is navigation large title area, you can make it inline

```
Spacer()
  .border(Color.gray)
  .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)   // inside NavigationView
```

Comment: `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` is also available.